# Error on Xcode beta 15.1 when building: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code. (Not using CocoaPods)

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, build-error

I am trying to build a Unity project(version 2023.1.9f1) on Xcode beta 15.1 and I am running into a build error when I try to archive it. Here is the error:

> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

It isn't the full error, but that's the main part.

Edit: It seems like that Xcode can't find any IPhone sdk, because it in the build log, it repeatedly says:

> Xcode needs to be installed in the /Applications directory and have a name matching Xcode*.app. Or be selected using xcode-select. It's also possible to use /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools if those match the listed requirements. More information and installation instructions can be found here: developer.apple.com/support/xcode Specific Xcode versions can be downloaded here: developer.apple.com/download/more
> Unable to detect any compatible iPhoneOS SDK!

The thing is though, I already have installed the IPhone sdk.
When I try to search this problem up, people keep saying things that are related to something called "CocoaPods" and I don't have this installed, so their solutions aren't working. This means I don't have the "pods" file/folder. I have also tried locking and unlocking "login" in Keychain access, but the lock button is greyed out for some reason. Again, I am just using Xcode, not CocoaPods. I am also not using Flutter.

I am following this video as a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4vX4JdIxv4

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the "main part" of the error.  That's the message that "something went wrong". You will need to dig into the build log to get the detail of what went wrong and why the build phase had a non zero exit code.

Comment: And, generally, I would advise against using beta tools and beta operating systems unless you are specifically testing for compatibility with those tools. A tutorial from 2 years ago certainly isn't going to require you to be using a current beta.

Comment: It seems like that Xcode can't find any IPhone sdk, because it in the build log, it repeatedly says: Xcode needs to be installed in the /Applications directory and have a name matching Xcode*.app. Or be selected using xcode-select.
It's also possible to use /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools if those match the listed requirements.

More information and installation instructions can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/

Specific Xcode versions can be downloaded here:
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Unable to detect any compatible iPhoneOS SDK!

Comment: When you install Xcode 15, it does not install the iPhone SDK automatically. If you run Xcode it should ask you if you want to install the iPhone SDK.

Comment: I installed it already though. Do I have to move it somewhere?

Comment: Did you specifically download and install the iPhone SDK from inside Xcode? Or did you just install Xcode?

Comment: When I launched Xcode for the first time, it asked me if I wanted to download a bunch of different sdks. I only downloaded the IPhone one.

Comment: I would start by deleting Xcode beta and re-installing from the Mac App Store.

Comment: should i install the same version?

Comment: The Mac App Store will have the currently released Xcode 15, not a beta version

Comment: I just did that, the same thing happened though.

Comment: Then sorry, I don't know. It is probably a Unity thing.